# How to find a row ID or column ID in smartsheet?

Tags: python, python-requests, smartsheet-api

I've been working with and reading the smartsheet API for a few hours now and I notice that in all the requests I have to make, I will need either a row ID or a column ID. I must be missing something easy here, but where do I find these IDs? Are they found through a query or somewhere on the actual view-able sheet?

Currently I am trying create a json object to send to me sheet and this is the code I have:

```
MySS = smartsheet.Smartsheet('*****************')
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer *****************", "Content-Type": 'application/json',
           "Accept": "application/json"}
row = MySS.Sheets.get_row(***********, HOW_DO_I_GET_THIS, include='discussions,attachments,columns,columnType')
r = requests.post("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/**********/rows", json=row, headers=headers)
```

The error message I get from this is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/**/**/**/***", line 89, in <module>
    headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 111, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'Error' object is not iterable
```

Honestly there are probably many things wrong with the code here, I just need some direction on where to find the row or column ID.
All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you execute the [Get Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) operation, the response will be a [Sheet object](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#sheet-object) that contains (amongst other things), a collection of **rows** and a collection of **columns** that the Sheet contains (including an **id** attribute for each row and each column).

The **Get Sheet** operation requires that you specify **sheetId**. You can get the Id of a Sheet either manually via the Smartsheet UI (via [Sheet properties](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/1205389-sheet-properties)) or via the API by using any operation that returns Sheet objects (for example: [List Sheets](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#list-sheets), [Get Folder](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-folder), [List All Contents](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#list-all-contents), [Search Everything](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#search-everything), etc.).