# Smartsheet API set start date

Tags: php, api, smartsheet-api

is there some possible way how to set End date for Gantt with Hard Deadline. Basicaly we have function which is teling us when stock is 0. We need to set this date as end date for our gantt.

Comment: Please provide some code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, i just trying API cals by Postman. Just few questions. How to get row id, and column id? Basicaly is in API doc called i cant set start and end date by API. Isnt there some possible way? Like some kind of "loophole" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Smartsheet API documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#column-types) -- "*the API does not support updating data in the End Date column under any circumstance*":

[image]

Re how to get row Id and column Id, see the answer to this other Stackoverflow post: [How to find a row ID or column ID in smartsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093751/how-to-find-a-row-id-or-column-id-in-smartsheet).